# Function for lagged sums

Tags: r

I know how to take the lagged difference:

```
delX = diff(x)
```

But the only way I know to take the lagged sum is:

```
sumY = apply(embed(c(0,y),2),1, sum)
```

Is there a function that can take the lagged sum? This way (or sliding the index in some other fashion) is not very intuitive.

Comment: An example would be helpful, I think. The meaning of "lagged sum" is not obvious to me. Maybe you just want `rowSums` of that `embed` thing?

Comment: All of the answers below are great, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for `filter`:

```
x <- 1:10
filter(x, filter=c(1,1), sides=1)
# [1] NA  3  5  7  9 11 13 15 17 19
```

You could also use `head` and `tail`:

```
head(x, -1) + tail(x, -1)
# [1]  3  5  7  9 11 13 15 17 19
```

Comment: The `head` and `tail` functions seem the most intuitive. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Two more options:

```
x <- 1:10
x + dplyr::lag(x)
# [1] NA  3  5  7  9 11 13 15 17 19
x + data.table::shift(x)
# [1] NA  3  5  7  9 11 13 15 17 19
```

Note that you can easily change the number of lags in both functions. Instead of lagging, you can also create a leading vector by using `dplyr::lead()` or `data.table::shift(x, 1L, type = "lead")`. Both functions also allow you to specify default values (which are `NA` by default).